# How to run package dependency with yarn in the console? Like npx tsc init for npm package.json with typescript dependency?

Tags: javascript, typescript, hadoop-yarn, package.json

I know `node_modules` folder does not exist when using yarn and instead there is a `.yarn/cache` folder where the dependencies go.

I have tried using `yarn dlx tsc init` and `npx tsc init` thinking they might work but they don't. There are many possible dev dependencies like esbuild, prettier.

Edit: I am using Yarn with the **Zero Installs** install strategy.

Comment: *I know node_modules folder does not exist when using yarn* ... really? All of my projects have node_modules and I almost exclusively use yarn